# What options are there to increase the level of a locus in Werewolf the Forsaken 1st edition?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, werewolf-the-forsaken

From what I can figure out there is a rule in the appendix about gathering 150 essence to either create or increase the level of a locus. However, there is also a ritual (Drawing down the Shadow) that will achieve the creation much much cheaper.

Is there something similar for increasing the level?

Answer (score 1):

## There is not a rite for increasing the level of a locus.

As you stated, the only RAW way to increase the level of a locus is to allow 150 essence to accumulate at the site of the locus, and then having it settle over the course of a week. The 150 essence can be provided either by an external source, or by preventing the essence the locus generates from being consumed.